# How can you get all the Apps on the Product Page to work on the Featured Product section on the home page?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I have spent hours looking through all the code on Shopify but can't seem to work out why I am unable to get all the apps that work on my product page, to work on the featured product section on the home page.

To give you an example of what I am trying to achieve, would be that I want to add what payment providers we use or the rating of reviews. These work fine on the product page but not on the featured product page.

Hope that makes sense to you. If not, please ask.

Comment: Because most of the apps rely on product object that is only available on Product page.

Comment: So would you say it's not possible to do it?

Comment: Depends on the app and available control. If it is your app or you want to do in theme, use all_products object to access products.

Comment: Thanks for the help